# Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'method group'

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

After the query execution the result I need to take is UserNames part.

I'm gettting an error: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'method group'

```
public class ProcessInput
{
    string connectionString = (string)ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["myConString"];
    private string msg_arr;
    string username = null;

    private void MooseSeenInput(string MobileNo, string Date, string odd, params Array[] msg_arr)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(myConString);
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Users as users WHERE UserName=@UserName AND State!='1' AND State!='4'", conn);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", UserName);
        // com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        using (SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    String UserNames = (reader.Read["users"]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error occurred at line:

```
String UserNames = (reader.Read["users"]);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your error is a compiler error as you were trying to apply index syntax onto a method call, which in C# involves brackets.

The `SqlDataReader` does expose an indexer, but it is on the reader itself, not a method member:

```
string username = (string)reader["users"];
```

This is how I tend to style this code:

```
using (SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader())
{
    int userOrd = reader.GetOrdinal("users");

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        string username = reader.GetString(userOrd);
    }
}
```

Note that I ask the reader for the ordinal prior to iterating an unknown number of records. This is good for two reasons:

1. I have cached the ordinal once and use it many times, this helps performance.
2. I have ***not*** hard-coded the ordinal so if someone were to change the column position in the result-set in the stored procedure / script, my code would continue to work.

Comment: +1 for getting the ordinal instead of hard coding it. I think that point would benefit from being stresed in your answer

Answer (score 6):

Use

```
   String UserNames = reader.GetString(0);
```

And as @leppie pointed in its comment, you could also use the field name as indexer
So supposing the field is named `users` you could also write this:

```
  String UserNames = reader["users"].ToString();
```

Comment: It does provide it. See the indexer.

Comment: @Steve A couple of points, calling `ToString` could hit a null or something that isn't a string, and hard-coding the ordinal isn't usually a good idea.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth I concur, but I have a doubt here. We could insert a `!reader.IsDBNull(ordinalPos)`, but if the field contains DBNull.Value then the ToString() translates to string.Empty and I don't know if this is what the user requires.

Answer (score 4):

Pretty sure you just wanna do:

```
String UserNames = reader["users"] as string;
```

Comment: @DaveBish My one gripe is if the column doesn't happen to be a string, this will yield a silent null (because `as` doesn't cause invalid cast exceptions).

Comment: I guess you need to ask "what should it return" if it is null, or not a string. I think that's very implementation specific.

Answer (score 3):

```
String UserNames;
if(reader["users"]!=null)     
UserNames = (string)reader["users"];//or reader["users"].ToString();
```

Comment: when i put DOT after the users there's NO tostring

Comment: @CoDeaDDict `ToString` and `(string)val` are not equivalent. When receiving a value, `ToString` will give you a string even if the data-type in SQL has changed. This could be a problem. I tend to favour casting from expected data types so if they change, the code fails and the change gets visibility.